# Fill 2 different PickerView

Tags: ios, swift, datapicker

I have 2 data pickers and I need to fill them with different data.
These data pickers are instances of class `AKPickerView`.

I have functions to fill them, but how I can do that with different information for every data picker view?

```
func numberOfItemsInPickerView(_ pickerView: AKPickerView) -> Int {
    return self.titles.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: AKPickerView, titleForItem item: Int) -> String {
    return self.titles[item]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: AKPickerView, didSelectItem item: Int) {
    print("Your favorite city is \(self.titles[item])")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have 2 instance properties that are  of type AKPickerView.
In each method, you can check if the given pickerView is equals to one of them and do things according to the result.

```
func numberOfItemsInPickerView(_ pickerView: AKPickerView) -> Int {
    if pickerView == self.myPicker1 {
        return data.count
    }
    return data2.count
}
```

Comment: ok, but how i can check that? 
previous, i used switch case, but now i don't know how to do that(

Comment: Check the example